# Update table SQL from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have table - 'GroupData' with data that contain group and date, and table - 'LastData' with last date per each group - last update in the past.
I try to write query that that update 'LastData' that at the end 'LastData' will contain one row per group and date = max(date) < now.

Result - change 'LastData' only one row per group. Date will be the max(date) < now - group number 1 there is 2 dates in the past, 01-01-2021 bigger then 01-01-2020 -> it will be in the result, group 2 there is only 1 date  01-02-2021 and it in the past -> it will be in the result and group number 3 w'ont be in result because the date in the future

GroupData

| group | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 |
| 2 | 01-02-2021 |
| 3 | 01-02-2022 |

LastData

| group | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 |

Result

| group | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 |
| 2 | 01-02-2021 |

Comment: please mention which dbms you are using.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: We need more detail here.  For example, it is not clear to me why the result of the above should end with 2021 for group 1 rather than group 2.  Within your question, please clarify the desired results.  Also, please update your question to include the tag for your MSSQL database.  This question will then be routed to people more attuned to that particular RDBMS rather than (just) people who know SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to delete matching rows before inserting into lastdata table you can use merge. When any group is available in lastdata then this query will check whether group wise max date from groupdata is older than the date in lastdata or not. If older then it will update lastdata table otherwise will do nothing.

And if there a group available in groupdata but not in lastdata then it will insert that row.

```
merge LastData ld
using(select [group],max(date) DATE from groupdata group by [group]) t ON T.[GROUP]=LD.[GROUP]
WHEN MATCHED AND T.DATE>LD.DATE THEN UPDATE SET LD.DATE=T.DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([GROUP],DATE)VALUES(T.[GROUP],T.DATE);
```

If you want to delete rows from lastdata when group is not available in groupdata you can add **When Not Matched By Source then delete** condition at the end as below:

```
merge LastData ld
    using(select [group],max(date) DATE from groupdata group by [group]) t ON T.[GROUP]=LD.[GROUP]
    WHEN MATCHED AND T.DATE>LD.DATE THEN UPDATE SET LD.DATE=T.DATE
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([GROUP],DATE)VALUES(T.[GROUP],T.DATE)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is `left join` and aggregation:

```
select gd.group,
       coalesce(min(case when gd.date >= ld.date then gd.date end),
                min(gd.date)
               )
from groupData gd left join
     lastData ld
     on gd.group = ld.group        
group by gd.group;
```